# How to use version.rb plugin in Jekyll static site generator

Tags: caching, plugins, jekyll, liquid

Here is the plugin code...

```
module Jekyll
  module VersionFilter
    def versioned_url(input)
      "#{input}?#{Time.now.to_i}"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::VersionFilter)
```

I am trying to cache bust/version control my .css file. I am new to Liquid. I am having trouble figuring out this basic plugin. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put version.rb into the _plugins/ directory in the root of your Jekyll site. If you don't have a _plugins/ directory, create one.

For usage - it looks like it gives a new filter that you can apply to text - so you'd use it in your templates to filter the references to your CSS files, adding the query string so that they aren't cached - but I'm sure there's more info on that wherever you got the code from.

For what it's worth, breaking caches with querystrings isn't the best solution. It'd probably be better to write a plugin that adds a new string to the actual filename, and then adds that string to the urls where those assets are included in the templates - but that is a bit more complex.

Comment: I am assuming that I would place my global.css url in the plugin like so   `def versioned_url(/css/global.css)`   Is this correct? Then place the liquid filter in my document head?

Comment: Not quite. You'd put the plugin in as it is, and then you could put your css in _config.yml like so: `css: /css/global.css`. In your template, you'd then put something like `<link href="{{ site.css | VersionFilter }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`. For what it's worth, I think this is a bit kludgy. If I get time, I might write a decent static asset manager/versioner for Jekyll (if there isn't one already).

Comment: Thanks @heliotrope. I didn't realize you could put your css file in the project _config.yml. That is pretty cool.  Although your solution did not work with `VersionFilter`. I used `versioned_url` and all works well. A cache busting plugin for Jekyll would be awesome. I searched for one last week and this is all that I found  https://github.com/krig/jekyll-plugins

Comment: This is the CSS I ended up using

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.css | versioned_url }}">

Answer (score 0):

If using an existing plugin for static asset versioning is an option for you, try [jekyll-minibundle](https://github.com/tkareine/jekyll-minibundle).

Assuming you keep non-stamped CSS files in `_styles` (note the _, because you don't want these to be exported to the production site) and want the stamped CSS files to appear in `css`, do the following:

```
<link href="{% ministamp _styles/site.css css/site.css %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection">
```

That works fine in combination with compass, just make compass export to `_styles`.